# cannot unpack non-iterable int object. BMI Calculator

Tags: python

I am trying to print out the number of people in each category of my BMI calculator. Receiving error: >
overweight, underweight, normal, obese = 0
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

```
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]
BMI_calc = []


def BMI(weights, heights):
    bmi_total = (weights * 703) / (heights ** 2)
    return bmi_total


def check(BMI):
  if BMI <= 18.5:
    print("Your underweight.")

  elif BMI > 18.5 and BMI < 24.9:
    print("You're normal weight.")

  elif BMI > 25 and BMI < 29.9:
    print("You're overweight.")

  elif BMI > 30:
    print("You're obese.")


for recipient in recipients:
    heights_ = int(input("What is your height " + recipient + "  :" ))
    weights_ = int(input("What is your weight " + recipient + "  :" ))
    BMI_info={"name":recipient,"weight":weights_,"height":heights_,"BMI":BMI(weights_, heights_)}
    BMI(BMI_info["weight"],BMI_info["height"])
    BMI_calc.append(BMI_info)



for person_info in BMI_calc:
    print(person_info["name"],end="\t")
    check(person_info["BMI"])


overweight, underweight, normal, obese = 0

def check(BMI):
  if BMI <= 18.5:
    print("Your underweight.")
    underweight += 1
  elif BMI > 18.5 and BMI < 24.9:
    print("You're normal weight.")
    normal += 1

  elif BMI > 25 and BMI < 29.9:
    print("You're overweight.")
    overweight +=1

  elif BMI > 30:
    print("You're obese.")
    obese += 1

print("This many people are" ,underweight)
```

I am trying to print out "This many people are underweight with the value of individuals it that category same for over, normal and obese.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error tells you what is going wrong.  It's on the following line

```
overweight, underweight, normal, obese = 0
```

What that line tries to do is "unpack" (or separate) out the right side of the equal sign and put it into each of the four variables on the left.  `0` cannot be broken part, it's not a tuple

If you want to initialize each variable to `0` simply do each on a different line.

Or you could assign them to a tuple that it's separated out

```
overweight, underweight, normal, obese = (0, 0, 0, 0)
```

But this seems like overkill and less readable IMO

**UPDATE**

Per comment below, since ints are immutable you can do the following

```
overweight = underweight = normal = obese = 0
```

Comment: Since `int` is immutable, it would be sufficient to write `overweight = underweight = normal = obese = 0` as well. I would still prefer four separate assignments, though.

Comment: Yeah that's fair.  I'll add that in as another alternative

Answer (score 1):

This problem is you're trying to assign a value to 4 different variables in one line, and python expects you to give a tuple containing 4 different values, not one; it doesn't broadcast your one value to 4 different variables.

You have 2 option, you can set the value of your variables to 0 in a different line like this:

```
overweight = 0
underweight = 0
normal = 0
obese = 0
```

Or you can do it in one line, but instead of only one 0, you should give a tuple containing four 0, like this:

```
overweight, underweight, normal, obese = (0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: FYI, parentheses not required.